# Preventing GPG logs from being mixed with output in terminal when using "-o -"

Tags: linux, terminal, gnupg

I've used GPG to encrypt string directly from terminal to file like this:

```
echo "Hello World!" | gpg -c --batch --passphrase SomePassword > some_filename
```

Now I'm trying to decrypt the file and to output the content in the terminal like this:

```
gpg --batch -o - --passphrase SomePassword some_filename
```

It works but the output starts with this two lines:

```
gpg: AES encrypted data
gpg: encrypted with 1 passphrase
```

NOTE:

The file does not contain this lines (so it's GPG output).

The version of GPG is 1.4.20

Comment: Questions about *using* UNIX tools, as opposed to questions about developing software, should be asked at [unix.se] or [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/), not StackOverflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, GnuPG outputs its messages to `stderr`, so You can eliminate them by redirecting `stderr` to `/dev/null`:

```
gpg -d --batch -o - --passphrase SomePassword some_filename 2> /dev/null
```